# How To Turn Off Logging in Scrapy (Python)

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

I have created a spider using Scrapy but I cannot figure out how to turn off the default logging.  From [the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html) it appears that I should be able to turn it off by doing

```
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
```

But this has no effect.  From looking at the code for logging.basicConfig() I'm guessing this is because "the root logger has handlers configured" but perhaps I'm wrong about that.  At any rate, can anyone explain what I need to do to get Scrapy to not output the usual

```
        2015-10-18 17:42:00 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: EF)
        2015-10-18 17:42:00 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: EF)
        2015-10-18 17:42:00 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
        2015-10-18 17:42:00 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
```

etc.?

EDIT:  As suggested by sirfz below, the line

```
        logging.getLogger('scrapy').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

can be used to set the logging level.  However, it appears that you must do this in the init method (or later) in your spider.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can simply change the logging level for scrapy (or any other logger):

```
logging.getLogger('scrapy').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

This disables all log messages less than the `WARNING` level.

To disable all scrapy log messages you can just set `propagate` to `False`:

```
logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False
```

This prevents scrapy's log messages from propagating to the root logger (which prints to console when configured using `basicConfig()`)

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I've figured out that setting the level works only if I put it in the __init__ of my spider.  I'm running my spider from a script -- if I set the logging level before I do start the crawl it (apparently) gets reset to INFO.  I'm not explicitly calling "configure_logging" but I guess Scrapy is doing that somewhere during startup. (?)

Comment: I never used scrapy myself but I guess the crawler is applying a default configuration for `logging` which is weird as this should be left for the user.

Answer (score 7):

You could add `-s LOG_ENABLED=False` as a parameter when launching your script. That should do the trick.

**Note**: For the version 1.1 changed a little bit: `-s LOG_ENABLED=0`

Comment: that works, but it's a bit radical, as it turns off all logging, including errors. You might try `-s LOG_LEVEL=WARNING` or another of the 5 log levels described here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#log-levels

Answer (score 4):

you can simply add `--nolog` 
 as a parameter when launching your spider using `scrapy` command
I am using scrapy v1.7.3. 
you can see more in help using command:

```
scrapy --help
```

Answer (score 1):

> logging.basicConfig(**kwargs)
>
> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers
>   configured for it.

Scrapy has handlers configured for it, so this will not work

Answer (score 1):

This might helpful, mentioned in the [document](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/logging.html) that you can add this to setting file:

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'WARNING'
```